# What's the difference when initializing an array declaration with a string literal and a list of distinct characters?

Tags: c++

```
char short_string[] = "abc"   
char short_string[] = {'a', 'b', 'c'}
```

what I think is the difference is that the 2nd line is a switch statement and that it requires input from user (either a b or c as the 1st line is more of a statement.... is this right ?

Comment: Not remotely. Which book are you learning C++ from?

Comment: The only difference is that the second one doesn't have a null terminator... but I second unapersson's question :)

Comment: [I can only repeat myself](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5947805/1968): get a C++ book and learn the basics of the language. We cannot teach you each and every aspect here. You lack even the most fundamental understanding of the language.

Comment: im using problem solving with c++ by walter savitch

Comment: I recommend you to go for something easier first, this book is for experts.

Answer (score 9):

No. That's not a switch statement.
Both lines are variable declarations with initialization. The difference is that:

```
char short_string[] = "abc"
```

Declares short_string null terminated c-string.
Memory dump: `0x61, 0x62, 0x63, 0x00`
Variable length in bytes: 4

While second line:

```
char short_string[] = {'a', 'b', 'c'}
```

Declares short_string as byte array.
Memory dump: `0x61, 0x62, 0x63`
Variable length in bytes: 3

Answer (score 0):

The first statement  declares and initializes a string  with the content `abc` (including terminating zero) -- this is a character array that is four characters long.

The second statement declares a character array with the three characters `a`, `b` and `c` -- it's *almost* the same thing as the first, except no terminating zero (not a proper string).

Also: **All statements in C/C++ must be terminated with a semicolon.**

Answer (score 0):

The difference is the first option will assign three characters and a trailing null ( x'00') 
the second option will assign the same three characters but no trailing null and would cause problems were you attempt to use any of the str.... family of functions.